# Stop EF Core to update model in db if model is tampered temporarily for front end logic processing and not called context.savechanges?

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model "product". Depending upon the logged-in user I tampered one of the attributes of the product model for this particular user via out the sessions , but don't want to permanently update that attribute in db. I am not calling context.savechanges() for this product model in the whole process for this particular user transaction, but still, db gets updated with the tampered value. How to stop ef core not to update this attribute except from the "POST" function which intentionally updates all attributes of product model class.
Please show me some direction?

Comment: Maybe you call ``context.savechanges()`` anywhere else on you context object, otherwise we need more detail and your code to find the problem

Comment: thanks @SaeedEsmaeelinejad you are right it was being used in the end path .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the model with `AsNoTracking()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking